# Azure event hub using terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I have question related to terraform code for azure event hub.
What are the security principles and policies that we need to take care while deploying azure event hub securely through terraform?. If possible please share the terraform code also.

Thanks

I have checked few docs but unable to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create an Azure event hub using Terraform:**

**Terraform Code:**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "venkyrg" {
  name     = "venkyrg1"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_eventhub_namespace" "example" {
  name                = "venkatnamespace"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.venkyrg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.venkyrg.name
  sku                 = "Standard"
  capacity            = 1

  tags = {
    environment = "Production"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_eventhub" "example" {
  name                = "venkateventhub"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.venkyrg.name
  partition_count     = 2
  message_retention   = 1
}

#Event hub Policy creation

resource "azurerm_eventhub_authorization_rule" "example" {
  name                = "navi"
  namespace_name      = azurerm_eventhub_namespace.example.name
  eventhub_name       = azurerm_eventhub.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.venkyrg.name
  listen              = true
  send                = false
  manage              = false
}

# Service Prinicipal Assignment

resource "azurerm_role_assignment" "pod-identity-assignment" {
  scope                = azurerm_resource_group.resourceGroup.id
  role_definition_name = "Azure Event Hubs Data Owner"
  principal_id         = "74cca40a-1d7e-4352-a66c-217eab00cf33"
}
```

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]

Once ran the code resources are created with event hub policies in **Azure** successfully, like below.

[image]

**Policy Status**:

[image]

Azure Built-in [roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/authorize-access-azure-active-directory) for **Azure Event Hubs**

Reference: [Azurerm-eventhub with Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/eventhub)